# What's the cleanest way to chain multiple optional query parameters in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What is the best way to chain multiple optional parameters to a query in hibernate?

Doing something like this feels very clunky, but I don't see a better way to do it:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("SELECT a from address a WHERE ");
    
if(!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(streetName)) {
  builder.append("a.streetName = :streetName AND ");
}
if(!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(houseNumber)) {
  builder.append("a.houseNumber = :houseNumber AND ");
}
if(!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(city)) {
  builder.append("a.city = :city AND ");
}
if(!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(countryCode)) {
  builder.append("a.countryCode = :countryCode AND ");
}
String sql = builder.substring(0, builder.length() - 4); //remove trailing 'AND'
  
TypedQuery<AddressEntity> query = entityManager.createQuery(sql, AddressEntity.class);
 
if(!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(streetName)) {
  query.setParameter("streetName", streetName);
}
if(!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(houseNumber)) {
  query.setParameter("houseNumber", houseNumber);
}
if(!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(city)) {
  query.setParameter("city", city);
}
if(!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(countryCode)) {
  query.setParameter("countryCode", countryCode);
}
  
return query.getResultList();
```

Comment: "query by example" sounds like a perfect macth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a parameter map...

```
    private static Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    parameters.put("streetName", "Linz");
    parameters.put("houseNumber", 1);
    
    String sql = parameters.entrySet().stream().map(e -> "a." + e.getKey() + " = :" + e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.joining(" AND "));
    
    TypedQuery<AddressEntity> query = entityManager.createQuery(sql, AddressEntity.class);
    
    parameters.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> query.setParameter(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

}